# iOS TableView not reloading if current view is tableViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview, reloaddata

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {
    // Handle the notificaton when the app is running

    NSLog(@"Recieved Notification %@",notif);

    NSLog(@"local notifications count = %d", [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]);
}
```

This is the method from app delegate, and I need to reload the table view when a notification arrives.

How can I implement the reloadData, since Xcode won't accept if I write "[TableViewController.tableView reloadData];"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Just do one thing, as you got the notification , post on more notification as follows in the method ....

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"RELOAD_DATA"object:nil];
}

//the add observer in viewDidLoad of that view controller where your table is added..

 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(receiveTableNotification:) 
    name:@"RELOAD_DATA"
    object:nil];

//and make a method in the same class 

- (void)receiveTableNotification:(NSNotification *)pNotification{
    [your_table_view reloadData];
}

//now remove obser in dealloc in your view controller class where you add observer .. 

- (void) dealloc
{

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [super dealloc];
 }
```

Comment: Bingo!!!!!!! Man, you just solved a problem I'm trying for 1 week now. Super thank you. Really. I can't explain how happy I am right now.

Comment: @Abhishek can we do it without notification? i am doing it in swift

Answer (score 0):

instead of `TableViewController.tableView` use `[self.viewController.tableView reloadData]`;

If your current view Controller is not the tableView, consider using `NSNotificationCenter` to post a reload notification

Comment: Could you post me an example of this? I'm new to iOS

Comment: did you try using this [self.viewController.tableView reloadData]?

Comment: Yes, when I write [self.TableViewController.tableView reloadData] Xcode gives me "propery 'TableViewController' not found on object of type 'AppNameAppDelegate'

Comment: post your code for - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions, so i can see what are your doing there

Comment: I got nothing in this AppDelegate method. just "return YES"

Is there something I should write on it?

Answer (score 0):

use `NSNotificationCenter postNotification:` mechanism for posting a reloadTable notification which you can catch in your class having tableViewController by `observer` to fire `reloadData` for your tableview

Answer (score 0):

Please call this in app deligate within the call backfunction

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notif {

      UINavigationController *navControl = [[[self tableViewController] viewControllers] objectAtIndex:lastObject]; //
         id Obj = [[navControl viewControllers] lastObject];
                if([Obj isKindOfClass:[Required class]])
                {
                   [Obj reloadDataOfTable];// made an function to desired class.
                }
}
```

Comment: do I put it exactly as it is here?

Comment: you need to make changes.... little bit... according to your class name and tableviewcontroller name

Comment: The problem is Xcode won't accept my tableView name. WHen I write [self TableViewController] I get errors saying no such property exists

Comment: please see the appdeligate class .h file and see the name of tableviewcontroller... you will get it.... you can also call it with .(DOT operator)